# How can you get the height metric of a string in PostScript?

Tags: string, fonts, metrics, postscript

You can obtain the width of a string in the current font with `stringwidth` and although this actually pushes offset coordinates on the stack, the y-value always seems to be useless. Is there a way to determine the exact height of a string, that may or may not include descenders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`stringwidth`, as it says, doesn't return string's height. (In all cases I looked at, the second integer on the stack after executing `stringwidth` was `0` -- for strings that run in horizontal direction.) `stringwidth` gives the relative coordinates of the currentpoint after executing a `(string) show`.

The PLRM has this to say about `stringwidth`:

> Note that the width returned by **stringwidth** is defined as movement of the current
>   point. It has nothing to do with the dimensions of the glyph outlines.

So what would work to take into account the string's height? The magic words to read up about in PRLM are `charpath` and `pathbbox`. Try this:

```
%!
/Helvetica findfont 60 scalefont setfont
200 700 4 0 360 arc fill 
200 700 moveto (test test) dup 
true charpath pathbbox 
3 -1 roll sub 2 div neg 3 1 roll sub 2 div exch 
1 0 0 setrgbcolor
200 700 moveto rmoveto show showpage
```

It calculates the string's (printed in red) height and uses that info to try and center a small filled circle (printed in black) into the center of its bounding box:

[image: Sample PostScript visualized]

Answer (score 5):

I have already answered this in [How to determine string height in PostScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3618194/36272), but it is useful here also.

Just adding to **pipitas** answer:

```
/textheight { 
    gsave                                  % save graphic context
    {                            
        100 100 moveto                     % move to some point 
        (HÍpg) true charpath pathbbox      % gets text path bounding box (LLx LLy URx URy)
        exch pop 3 -1 roll pop             % keeps LLy and URy
        exch sub                           % URy - LLy
    }
    stopped                                % did the last block fail?
    {
        pop pop                            % get rid of "stopped" junk
        currentfont /FontMatrix get 3 get  % gets alternative text height
    }
    if
    grestore                               % restore graphic context
} bind def

/jumpTextLine { 
    textheight 1.25 mul                    % gets textheight and adds 1/4
    0 exch neg rmoveto                     % move down only in Y axis
} bind def
```

The method expects that some font is already set. It works over the selected font (`setfont`) and its size (`scalefont`).

I use (HÍpg) to get the biggest bounding box possible, using accentuated uppercase characters and "below line" characters. The result is good enough.

The alternative approach steals from **dreamlax**'s answer -- some fonts do not support `charpath` operator.

Saving and restoring the graphic context keeps the current point in place, so it has no impact over the "flow" of your document.

Hope I've helped.

Comment: Additionally, you can use `currentfont /FontBBox get` for the bounding box, instead of using the `charpath pathbbox` to get it... in my case, it worked perfectly under GhostScript; however, the result was not good when interpreted by the printer.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work most of the time:

```
/fontheight { currentfont /FontMatrix get 3 get } bind def
/lineheight { fontheight 1.2 mul } bind def
```

It won't work for all `/FontType`s.

Comment: This also won't work if there's any Y-shear in the matrix. If `/FontMatrix get 5 get` is not zero, then the height of a glyph will depend on its width.

Comment: to work for more font types you need to use FontBBox as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296322/how-to-determine-height-and-depth-of-a-postscript-font/19263342#19263342