# How can I have text shrink automatically depending on the character length in Postscipt? Or to have the text resize in order to fit a fixed area?

Tags: text, postscript

How can I have the text size shrink automatically depending on character length in Postscipt? Or to have the text resize in order to fit a fixed area?

Comment: You want to use `stringwidth`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618194/how-to-determine-string-height-in-postscript for a related discussion.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's simpler to make a 1-pt font, measure,and then scale *up*. Something like (untested)

```
/showwid { % string width /font-name
    gsave
    1 selectfont
    1 index stringwidth pop div % width/stringwidth
    currentfont scalefont setfont
    show
    grestore
} def
```

This code doesn't account for height at all.

Answer (score 1):

The way i do it is:

- get string width
- divide area width by string width
- multiply current font size by that
- then use this as new font size and show

So, the code is something like:

```
%some bogus vars to make it understandable
/myfont /Helvetica def
/mysz 10 def
/mywidth 100 def
/mystr (Hello PS world!) def

%supposedly you'd be in the middle of something
%therefore we would have the font already selected
myfont mysz selectfont

50 50 moveto
myfont mywidth mystr stringwidth pop div mysz mul selectfont
mystr show

% and for good measure, a line showing the size
50 49 moveto
mywidth 0 rlineto stroke
```